# Some dll missing when installshield setup build using MSBuild ( but VS2012 build proper output )?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, msbuild, installshield, tfsbuild

When we build our VS2012 wpf solution with InstallShield Setup (installshield 2013 limited or professional), in VS2012 it create setup with all dll reference with it . But when we build it in TFS or MSbuild in local setup don't have all dll reference in it (in my case some devexpress theme dll missing ). 
 We add Reference to project in installshield setup and set find dependency to auto .

local MSBuild command is :

> D:\Projects\installShieldThemeIssue>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" 
>   /property:InstallShieldpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2013LE\System" /filelogge

Our project is in active development so we cannot able to add all dll manually , is any option to fix it .( When i check find out that this problem for that dll not have direct call , like theme dll's is it a Installshield error) .
 I don't see any option to add log file in post so skydive link added below 
link https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D54B0993343A8868!264&authkey=!AH4kAIK_ok6BKn4

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, the use of dynamic installer authoring during the build defeats the declarative nature of windows installer.  I prefer deterministic / static authoring over sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

[Dealing with very large number of files](http://blog.iswix.com/2007/06/dealing-with-very-large-number-of-files.html)